# How can I set a select value with jQuery

Tags: java, jquery, spring, spring-mvc

This is my select:

```
<springform:select style="display:none;" id="produtoCabal" class="input g270" path="produtoCabal" value="${plastico.plastico.codProdutoCabal}" onchange="ativaListagem();">
     <option value=""></option>
</springform:select>
```

And I want to change the value of the selected value with a jQuery function but its not working, I've already tried these options:

```
    function carregarProdutoCabal() {
        $("select#produtoCabal option:checked" ).val(-1);
        $("select#produtoCabal" ).val(-1);
        $("#produtoCabal" ).val(-1);
}
```

Comment: Do you have an `<option>` in that select with `value="-1"`?

Comment: how can you `select` it if `style="display:none;"` ?